# How can I add a gradient background to the MauiSplashScreen in Maui framework?

Tags: c#, .net, mobile, blazor, maui

I'm working on a project using the Maui framework and I would like to customize the MauiSplashScreen by adding a gradient background. However, I couldn't find any built-in support for this feature. Is there a way to achieve a gradient background effect on the MauiSplashScreen? If so, can you provide guidance on how to implement it? Any code examples or references to relevant documentation would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

`<MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Images\hikari_white_rings.svg" Color="#000000" Resize="false"/>`

I thought this would've worked but I was wrong I think the complier for the different platforms can't take gradient colors and it it's not even xaml in that file. its .csproj.

```
<MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" ForegroundFile="Resources\images\hikari_white_rings.svg">
<MauiIcon.Background>
    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0" StartPoint="0,1">
        <GradientStop Color="#808080" Offset="0" />
        <GradientStop Color="#000080" Offset="1" />
    </LinearGradientBrush>
</MauiIcon.Background>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A gradient background effect can not be achieved by using the LinearGradientBrush at the MauiSplashScreen.

You can create a gradient background picture and set the picture as a MauiSplashScreen.

Here is the information about [Add a splash screen to a .NET MAUI app project.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/images/splashscreen?tabs=android)